# Handling executed system command errors in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, system, lib

There is `system()` function from `os` library, however it can't handle errors. I know it returns error codes ( For example, when command is executed successfully, it returns `0`. ) but it doesn't throws any exceptions so I can't handle these errors with `try-except` keyword. Is there a function that throws error that can handled with `try-except`?

It would be better if that function is in a built-in library like `os` or `sys`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to catch exception from a system() command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196002/how-to-catch-exception-from-a-system-command-in-python)

Comment: Nah, it doesn't.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example with code and specify what it does and how that differs from what you want?

Comment: I did it using `subprocess.check_call()` function. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some testing, and I couldn't figure it out either. So I Googled your question and found [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86522/os-system-subprocess-call-error-handling-when-error-in-command-line-function/277526), which should answer your question. If it doesn't help, I don't know of any other possible fixes to your problem.

Comment: Well, I did more research and I found `subprocess.check_call()` function. It throws errors so it works. I can handle it with `try-except`. Thank you anyways!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.